# cairomm draw single pixel

Tags: c++, cairo

I've a simple boolean matrix I want to see it as an Image. I am using Cairomm. In documentations I see how to draw a line, curve, arc. But I just want to put black and white color to each pixels. Not getting any docs on pixel access. This is what I copied from examples. though I want a monochrome image. Not `FORMAT_ARGB32`

```
  Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::ImageSurface> surface = Cairo::ImageSurface::create(Cairo::FORMAT_ARGB32, matrix.cols(), matrix.rows());
  Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> context = Cairo::Context::create(surface);
```

right now I am drawing an 1 pixel line

```
  context->set_antialias(Cairo::ANTIALIAS_NONE);

  context->save(); // save the state of the context
  context->set_source_rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  context->paint(); // fill image with the color
  context->restore(); // color is back to black now

  context->set_source_rgb(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  context->set_line_width(1.0);
  context->move_to(1.0, 1.0);
  context->line_to(2.0, 2.0);
  context->stroke();
```

Is this okay or there is something like `context->draw(row, col, color)` ?

Answer (score 0):

An ImageSurface has a get_data() method. Together with flush() (before modifying data directly) and mark_dirty() (afterwards), you can use this to modify the pixel data directly and set individual pixels.

http://cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/classCairo_1_1ImageSurface.html#a94ba52fe4a201579c8a5541717822bdb

Comment: Hello Uli Schlachter, I can't find the documentation to know how the pixels are stored inside the data property. Do you know what's the structure? I've tried assuming [a, r, g, b] but it didn't work.

Comment: This depends on the format of the image surface. The "most common ones" are uint32_t quantities containing the components: http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-t (You also want to look at the stride of the image surface which is the distance in bytes between rows in the image)